# Z_Construct_UClass_ATank_NoRegister() - problem with unreal engine enhanced input

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

This is what I currently get when I try to compile my project:

```
Setting up bundled DotNet SDK
/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_5.3/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Mac/../../../Binaries/ThirdParty/DotNet/6.0.302/mac-arm64
Running dotnet Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool/UnrealBuildTool.dll -ModuleWithSuffix=ToonTanks,4369 ToonTanksEditor Mac Development -Project=/Users/o/Documents/Unreal Projects/ToonTanksProjectSetup_4.25/ToonTanks/ToonTanks.uproject /Users/o/Documents/Unreal Projects/ToonTanksProjectSetup_4.25/ToonTanks/ToonTanks.uproject -architecture=arm64 -IgnoreJunk
Log file: /Users/o/Library/Application Support/Epic/UnrealBuildTool/Log.txt
Parsing headers for ToonTanksEditor
  Running Internal UnrealHeaderTool "/Users/o/Documents/Unreal Projects/ToonTanksProjectSetup_4.25/ToonTanks/ToonTanks.uproject" "/Users/o/Documents/Unreal Projects/ToonTanksProjectSetup_4.25/ToonTanks/Intermediate/Build/Mac/ToonTanksEditor/Development/ToonTanksEditor.uhtmanifest" -WarningsAsErrors -installed
Total of 2 written
Reflection code generated for ToonTanksEditor in 1.6008434 seconds
Building ToonTanksEditor...
[Upgrade]
[Upgrade] Using backward-compatible include order. The latest version of UE has changed the order of includes, which may require code changes. The current setting is:
[Upgrade]     IncludeOrderVersion = EngineIncludeOrderVersion.Unreal5_0
[Upgrade] Suppress this message by setting 'IncludeOrderVersion = EngineIncludeOrderVersion.Latest;' in ToonTanksEditor.Target.cs.
[Upgrade] Alternatively you can set this to 'EngineIncludeOrderVersion.Latest' to always use the latest include order. This will potentially cause compile errors when integrating new versions of the engine.
[Upgrade]
Determining max actions to execute in parallel (10 physical cores, 10 logical cores)
  Executing up to 10 processes, one per physical core
------ Building 5 action(s) started ------
[1/5] Compile [Apple] Tank.gen.cpp
/Users/o/Documents/Unreal Projects/ToonTanksProjectSetup_4.25/ToonTanks/Intermediate/Build/Mac/UnrealEditor/Inc/ToonTanks/UHT/Tank.gen.cpp:14:2: error: unknown type name 'ENHANCEDINPUT_API'
        ENHANCEDINPUT_API UClass* Z_Construct_UClass_UInputAction_NoRegister();
        ^
/Users/o/Documents/Unreal Projects/ToonTanksProjectSetup_4.25/ToonTanks/Intermediate/Build/Mac/UnrealEditor/Inc/ToonTanks/UHT/Tank.gen.cpp:14:26: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
        ENHANCEDINPUT_API UClass* Z_Construct_UClass_UInputAction_NoRegister();
                                ^
                                ;
/Users/o/Documents/Unreal Projects/ToonTanksProjectSetup_4.25/ToonTanks/Intermediate/Build/Mac/UnrealEditor/Inc/ToonTanks/UHT/Tank.gen.cpp:94:306: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Z_Construct_UClass_UInputAction_NoRegister'; did you mean 'Z_Construct_UClass_ATank_NoRegister'?
        const UECodeGen_Private::FObjectPropertyParams Z_Construct_UClass_ATank_Statics::NewProp_MoveAction = { "MoveAction", nullptr, (EPropertyFlags)0x0040000000000015, UECodeGen_Private::EPropertyGenFlags::Object, RF_Public|RF_Transient|RF_MarkAsNative, nullptr, nullptr, 1, STRUCT_OFFSET(ATank, MoveAction), Z_Construct_UClass_UInputAction_NoRegister, METADATA_PARAMS(UE_ARRAY_COUNT(Z_Construct_UClass_ATank_Statics::NewProp_MoveAction_MetaData), Z_Construct_UClass_ATank_Statics::NewProp_MoveAction_MetaData) };
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Z_Construct_UClass_ATank_NoRegister
/Users/o/Documents/Unreal Projects/ToonTanksProjectSetup_4.25/ToonTanks/Intermediate/Build/Mac/UnrealEditor/Inc/ToonTanks/UHT/Tank.gen.cpp:24:10: note: 'Z_Construct_UClass_ATank_NoRegister' declared here
        UClass* Z_Construct_UClass_ATank_NoRegister()
                ^
3 errors generated.
[2/5] Compile [Apple] ToonTanks.init.gen.cpp
[3/5] Compile [Apple] Tank.cpp
Total time in Parallel executor: 4.71 seconds
Total execution time: 7.35 seconds
```

This is my code:

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "BasePawn.h"
#include "Tank.generated.h"

/**
 *
 */


UCLASS()
class TOONTANKS_API ATank : public ABasePawn
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    ATank();

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

private:
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, Category = "Components")
    class USpringArmComponent* SpringArm;

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, Category = "Components")
    class UCameraComponent* Camera;

    void Move(float Value);

    // This property bellow

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = Input, meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
    class UInputAction* MoveAction;

};
```

When I comment that two lines under `// This property bellow` for `MoveAction`, the project compiles.

What's going on?

I tried debugging, commenting and checking older project with similar enhanced input.

Same situation with `UInputMappingContext`.

If it helps, `GENERATED_BODY` is marked as red with this error:

> this declaration has no storage class or type specifier.

But as I know, VS Code with c++ intellisense is not the best thing.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem - probably also while using the same course material - and apparently there is a manual thing we need to do in a file that's not mentioned a lot - it's the

```
ToonTanks.build.cs
```

That is used by the Unreal Engine build tool and it includes Module Dependencies - and to use the Enhanced Input, it needs to be manually included in the list of dependencies, like:

[image: Enhanced Input in the module dependency array]

It can be either added to the Public or the Private list but it needs to be there, otherwise the builder won't find it and compilation will fail.

Good luck!